# Custom return type for Supabase

Tags: typescript, supabase

```
interface Account {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    created: string;
}

export async function getAccounts() : Promise<Account[]> {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('account')
        .select()

    if (error) throw error
    return data;  <- error shows here
}
```

The code still works but Typescript gives me a warning. I want it to return the Account[] datatype so that I can have auto-completion when I use this function. Is there any method to do so?

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs, this is how you do it with TypeScript:
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/typescript-support

1. Generate the types from your database

```
$ supabase start
$ supabase gen types typescript --local > lib/database.types.ts
```

2. Pass the generated type in the generics slot when you create your client:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { Database } from 'lib/database.types'

const supabase = createClient<Database>(
 process.env.SUPABASE_URL,
 process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
)
```

3. Let TypeScript work out the types for you:

```
export async function getAccounts() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('account')
        .select()

    if (error) throw error
    return data;
}

 export type AccountResponse = ReturnType<typeof getAccount>
 export type AccountResponseSuccess = AccountResponse['data']
 // export type AccountResponseError = AccountResponse['error']
```

4. Usage:

```
const accounts: AccountResponse = await getAccounts();
```